# Dropdown menu displaying to the right of li instead of below

Tags: html, css

I would like the submenu to be displayed dropdown when my mouse is obove the respective item, but when i place the mouse over it, the submenu appears to the right of the main menu, not below.

Ive tried doing it by setting a fixed width for the items on the menu but it doesnt seem to work properly.

How can i make it work the expected way?

My HTML Code:

```css
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

.elementoMenu a {
  float: left;
  color: #ff9900;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.elementoMenu a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ff9900;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.elementoMenu a:first-child:hover+.submenu, .submenu:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #663300;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li class="elementoMenu">
   <a href="">Inicio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="elementoMenu">
    <a href="">Carta</a>
    <div class="submenu">
     <a href="1.html">Platos de Tandoori</a>
     <a href="1.html">Platos de Curry</a>
     <a href="1.html">Arroces</a>
     <a href="1.html">Platos vegetales</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="elementoMenu">
    <a href="">Menú</a>
    <div class="submenu">
     <a href="1.html">Menú del día</a>
     <a href="1.html">Menú degustación</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="elementoMenu">
    <a href="">Restaurante</a>
    <div class="submenu">
     <a href="1.html">Nuestra historia</a>
     <a href="1.html">Cómo llegar</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="elementoMenu">
    <a href="">Reservas</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display `block` instead of `inline-block` :

```css
.elementoMenu a:first-child:hover+.submenu, .submenu:hover {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #663300;
}
```

Here's the full code, please check:

```css
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.elementoMenu a {
  color: #ff9900;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.elementoMenu a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ff9900;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.elementoMenu a:first-child:hover+.submenu, .submenu:hover {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #663300;
}
```

```html
         <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="elementoMenu">
                    <a href="">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="elementoMenu">
                    <a href="">Carta</a>
                    <div class="submenu">
                        <a href="1.html">Platos de Tandoori</a>
                        <a href="1.html">Platos de Curry</a>
                        <a href="1.html">Arroces</a>
                        <a href="1.html">Platos vegetales</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="elementoMenu">
                    <a href="">Menú</a>
                    <div class="submenu">
                        <a href="1.html">Menú del día</a>
                        <a href="1.html">Menú degustación</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="elementoMenu">
                    <a href="">Restaurante</a>
                    <div class="submenu">
                        <a href="1.html">Nuestra historia</a>
                        <a href="1.html">Cómo llegar</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="elementoMenu">
                    <a href="">Reservas</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: @LucasMartinez I updated my answer, please check. I removed the float: left on "nav ul li" and ".elementoMenu a".

Comment: Please let me know if this is still not the one you're looking for.